# Log4j issue with cdh4 hadoop

Tags: hadoop, log4j, cloudera-manager

I have a cluster of hadoop cdh4.5 managed using cloudera manager. I have a custom log4j.properties file with specific configurations. I have added this log4j.properties through cloudera manager to the cluster (for each process too ie., namenode,datanode,jobtracker,tasktracker). But it was not taken by the hadoop. Has anyone faced this problem earlier?

Before using cdh4, I used hadoop-0.20.2 and just having this log4j.properties in hadoop configuration was enough to pick it. So is this issue anyway related to cloudera manager?